# \1 - what does this sed action mean?

Tags: sed, json

I am using this sed command to extract a json value for a key, say MyKey..

```
sedPattern='s/^.*"myKey":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'
```

For a json string like,

```
{"myKey" : 1, "yourKey": 2}
```

It returns what i need,

```
1
```

But what does `\1` action in the above sed command mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\([^"]*\)` defines a group of characters, the group is actually the found contents between the two braces (), the braces need to be escaped hence `\(` and `\)`

`\1` is the contents of the first group

There could be several groups defined using multiple sets of brace pairs, they are numbered incrementally and each one can be referenced as `\n` (e.g. `\1`, `\2`, `\3` etc) hence the name: *backreference*.

Answer (score 0):

`\1` is a back-reference to the substring captured by the first group, i.e. the first `\(...\)` in the expression.  If you have nested groups, then the first one is the one with the left-most `\(` in the expression.

In your example, it's the substring matched by `[^"]*` (a possibly empty string of non-double quotes) at a particular position in the string.

A better and safer way to parse JSON is with using a JSON-aware tool, like `jq`:

```bsh
jq -r '.myKey' document.json
```

This not only allows you to extract your data using a structured language, but also ensures that the data that you extract is decoded from possibly having been JSON-encoded.

I'm noting that your `sed` expression *doesn't at all* extract `1` from the given JSON document unless you rewrite the document as

```json
{"myKey":"1","yourKey":2}
```

This document is different in two aspects:

1. The whitespace between keys and values is different.  This does not matter for a JSON parser, but matters a lot to a line-based tool that is not aware of JSON structures.
2. The type of the value for the `myKey` key is now a string rather than a number.  This matters to a parser depending on what it does with the value.  It may have to be converted to a value, or it may be *expected* to be a string.  It depends on the application using the data.

Also note that this document is *equivalent* to

```json
{
  "myKey": "1",
  "yourKey": 2
}
```

and that a JSON parser would see no difference between the two of them, while `sed` may be able to extract something out of one of the documents but not the other.