# rename the header of multifasta files in bioinformatics

Tags: bash, shell, awk, bioinformatics

here is my file1.fa(seqID, \t, sequence), it's not a standard fasta format file.

```
abc MFSKPTKAPLNKGQEAVAKEFFDFLLDPNATEFNISGPGGTGKTFLMSHLIDDTMPA
cef AFSKPTKAPLNKGQEAVAKEFFDFLLDPNATEFNESGPGGTGKTFLMSHLIDDTMFA
rig AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGEGKFKKKKKSKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
```

Now i want to convert it to standard fasta format like this:

```
>abc
MFSKPTKAPLNKGQEAVAKEFFDFLLDPNATEFNISGPGGTGKTFLMSHLIDDTMPA
>cef 
AFSKPTKAPLNKGQEAVAKEFFDFLLDPNATEFNESGPGGTGKTFLMSHLIDDTMFA
>rig 
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGEGKFKKKKKSKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
```

I have tried like that, but i don't konw how to add the ">", anybody can help me?

```
less -S file1.fa | sed 's/\t/\n/g' > file2.fa
```

Comment: Is the sequence data guaranteed to be on a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `sed`  without using `less`. You can also edit the file *in-place* without redirecting the output to new file.

Your `sed` command would become:

```bash
sed -i'.bak' 's/\(.*\)\t/>\1\n/g' file1.fa
```

Or if you don't to want to edit *in-place* you can use:

```bash
sed  's/\(.*\)\t/>\1\n/g' file1.fa > file2.fa
```

Comment: If you have doubts about `\(.*\)` and `\1` you can see these answers; [link1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236920/1-what-does-this-sed-action-mean) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609949/what-does-1-in-sed-do). I believe they explain better than what I could explain :).

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
raku -pe 's/^ (<:Ll>+) (\s) />$0\n/;'   

#OR

raku -pe 's/^ <((<:Ll>+) (\s))> <:Lu>+ />$0\n/;'
```

These answers use Raku's `:Ll` (Unicode Letter-lowercase) and `:Lu` (Unicode Letter-uppercase) character class definitions:

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Unicode_properties

If you prefer you can simply substitute `\S+` to denote one-or-more non-whitespace characters. You can also change `\s` to the more-specific `\t` token.

In the second example, Raku's `<(`…`)>` capture markers instruct Raku to drop everything outside from the match object, so the `<:Lu>+` gets matched--but not deleted--in the replacement.

Sample Input:

```
abc MFSKPTKAPLNKGQEAVAKEFFDFLLDPNATEFNISGPGGTGKTFLMSHLIDDTMPA
cef AFSKPTKAPLNKGQEAVAKEFFDFLLDPNATEFNESGPGGTGKTFLMSHLIDDTMFA
rig AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGEGKFKKKKKSKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
```

Sample Output:

```
>abc
MFSKPTKAPLNKGQEAVAKEFFDFLLDPNATEFNISGPGGTGKTFLMSHLIDDTMPA
>cef
AFSKPTKAPLNKGQEAVAKEFFDFLLDPNATEFNESGPGGTGKTFLMSHLIDDTMFA
>rig
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGEGKFKKKKKSKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://conf.raku.org/talk/156
https://raku.org