# How to extract text between two strings

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have string like this and trying to extract the text between two strings.

Example:

```
[{a12:12},{b12:1},{m12:34},{b12:2},{k12:45}]
```

I want to extract the only value between `b12` and `},{m12:` and my required output is `1`.

I tried `sed` and not getting expected output. Not sure if it is due to multiple occurrences of `b12`. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Are you working on a json inout file?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the input is valid JSON:

```json
[{"a12":12},{"b12":1},{"m12":34},{"b12":2},{"k12":45}]
```

... we may use `jq` to extract the first element of the top-level array that has a `b12` key and then extract the key's value from that element:

```bash
jq 'map(select(has("b12"))) | first.b12' file
```

With the key's name as an command-line argument:

```bash
jq --arg k 'b12' 'map(select(has($k))) | first[$k]' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` you can extract the `1` by specifying a *matching group* between your given strings. Btw, you said you want the string between `b12` and `},{m12:` but the output in this case would be `:1`. So what you really want is the text between `b12:` and `},{m12:`. 
So the code should look like this:

```bash
echo '[{a12:12},{b12:1},{m12:34},{b12:2},{k12:45}]' | sed  's/.*b12:\(.*\)},{m12:.*/\1/'
```

or

```
sed  's/.*b12:\(.*\)},{m12:.*/\1/' <<< '[{a12:12},{b12:1},{m12:34},{b12:2},{k12:45}]'
```

The pattern `s/.*b12:\(.*\)},{m12:.*/\1/` will replace `b12:` and all what you have before it (**.*b12:**) and it will also replace `},{m12:` and all what you have after it (**},{m12:.***) by the matched group. Where `\(.*\)` is the matched group (**in your case the `1`**) and the pattern `\1` represents to this one.

**Note**
Using this `sed` command you might have *"issues"*. For example, if you had more `m12` like these:

```
'[{a12:12},{b12:1},{m12:34},{b12:2},{m12:45}]'
'[{a12:12},{b12:1},{m12:34},{b12:2},{m12:10},{m12:45}]'
```

The output will be (respectively):

```
2
2},{m12:10
```

So the best option to do what you want is by using the [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/723610/414186)

---

You could read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236920/1-what-does-this-sed-action-mean) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609949/what-does-1-in-sed-do) to be able to understand how *matched groups* work.

Comment: If there is an m12 somewhere else along in his string, and we've seen these can exist multiple times in the case of b12, then the matched group .* being greedy will contain not just the 1, but also everything else in between the first b12 and last m12.Something like ([0-9]+) can work better imo.

Comment: @seshoumara thanks for the comment! In fact, my sed command has some *"issues"*, similarly what you said. I will better update my answer to provide more details.